Django Models NOT raising IntegrityError when supposed to for a duplicate entry
I am making a custom Django command to update my database using a JSON file containing the required data. Here is what the code for it looks like at the moment:
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from base.models import Teams, Players, Accounts
from pathlib import Path
import json
from riotwatcher import LolWatcher
from decouple import config
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        filepath = Path(__file__).parent / "db_players.json"
        with open(filepath, "r") as f:
            teams_players = json.loads(f.read())

        for team in teams_players["teams"]:
            try:
                this_team = Teams(team_name=team["team_name"], team_shortname=team["team_shortname"], team_region=team["team_region"])
                this_team.save()
            except Exception as e:
                self.stderr.write(repr(e))
                this_team = Teams.objects.get(team_name=team["team_name"])

            for player in team["players"]:
                try:
                    this_player = Players(player_ign=player["player_ign"], player_role=player["player_role"], team=this_team)
                    this_player.save()
                except Exception as f:
                    self.stderr.write(repr(f))
                    this_player = Players.objects.get(player_ign=player["player_ign"])
                
                for account in player["accounts"]:
                    
                    try:
                        this_account = Accounts(account_puuid=account["account_puuid"], account_region=account["account_region"], player=this_player)
                        this_account.save()
                        self.stdout.write(f"Account added: {account['account_puuid']}")
                    except:
                        self.stderr.write("Account already exists.")
                        this_account = Accounts.objects.get(account_puuid=account["account_puuid"])

And here's an example of what the JSON file looks like:
    "teams":[
        {
            "team_name": "G2 Esports",
            "team_shortname": "G2",
            "team_region": "EUW1",
            "players":[
                {
                    "player_ign": "Caps",
                    "player_role": "MIDDLE",
                    "accounts":[
                        {
                            "account_puuid": "HpsKHYTCkVOIC2VMrxWbKQoPgfz2YIjQxQqZJHMUT2_AvEpTnrZPZsDM13MG-j3EM5szm-qUsb_HJw",
                            "account_region": "EUW1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

And lastly the code for these models:

class Teams(models.Model):
    team_id = models.SmallAutoField(primary_key=True)
    team_name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)
    team_shortname = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)
    team_region = models.CharField(max_length=4)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'teams'


class Players(models.Model):
    player_id = models.SmallAutoField(primary_key=True)
    player_ign = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20)
    player_role = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    team = models.ForeignKey('Teams', models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'players'


class Accounts(models.Model):
    account_puuid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=78)
    account_region = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    player = models.ForeignKey('Players', models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'accounts'

There are no issues when it comes to adding a new team or player model instance; if it is a duplicate of what is already in the database, it will raise an exception and the code in "except" will run. However, whenever it is time to add an account, it will always "add" a new account without fail. Even when the account already exists in the database, it will still "add" the account. I have no idea why it does this.
Here's the output when I run the command (named updateaccounts).
Version of everything in the project:
asgiref==3.8.1
certifi==2024.2.2
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
Django==4.2.11
djangorestframework==3.15.1
idna==3.7
mysqlclient==2.2.4
python-decouple==3.8
requests==2.31.0
riotwatcher==3.3.0
sqlparse==0.4.4
typing_extensions==4.11.0
tzdata==2024.1
urllib3==2.2.1

